# Book Identification: Story set on 'abandoned' spaceship with an A.I. over crackly loudspeakers

Tags: story-identification, novel, spaceship

I read this book back in the late 90s, early 2000s at my public library, although the book seemed a little worn, probably came out in the 80s or so. It was a Young Adult Sci-Fi action, if I remember correctly.

Our protagonist(s) either wake up on, or are sent to investigate a (space) ship. I believe it was one of 'ours', but it had suffered damage and was abandoned.

The most vivid thing I remember was there was an A.I coming over the speakers, who was happy they were there, it's memory had been pulled and it had lost automatic control over most of the ships functions. I remember they made the point that the speakers were really crackly, and that the voice sounded warped, like a warped tape or something.

The A.I was telling them how to re-activate life support and a few other essentials, as well as restore its control over the ship and its memories, so they could figure out what happened.

Near the end, they manage to 'fix' the A.I. and it regains control, and the crackly warped voice is replaced by a clear, soft voice. Of course, in true A.I. fashion, it remembers that it was homicidal, and that the original crew was trying to disable it to stop it from gassing them. They failed, but not before blowing out most of it's systems.

I can't remember what happens in the very end, but I'm pretty sure the protagonist makes it out alive.

I know, the last part sounds a lot like Portal, which is why I haven't been able to find any info on it. Portal seems to steal all the search results.

Comment: Portal? It almost sounds like the 90s amazing game Marathon, which begot Halo. But of course,  that has aliens in it too

Comment: possibly related to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/242583/book-about-ai-called-angels-who-look-after-a-child-left-alone-on-a-spaceship

Answer (score 5):

There is some deviation from my memory of the story, but there are certainly aspects which match Angel One and Angel Two of Earthsearch by James Follett, originally a radio series broadcast by BBC Radio 4 in the late seventies/early eighties and novelised by the author.

Comment: I think yours is the closest.

Comment: Can you actually say which aspects match?

Answer (score 4):

This sounds very much like the story line of a game that failed to reach its crowdfunding target on Kickstarter in 2013, called Dark Matter.  I tried to find out where they got their story line, but to no avail.  I'm also interested.

Answer (score 3):

Some of the details seem to match up with *Children of the Jedi* by Barbara Hambly: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Children_of_the_Jedi

Answer (score 3):

[*The Last Angel*](https://forums.spacebattles.com/threads/the-last-angel.244209/) is what I think you're looking for.

An excerpt from the summary on the [TV Tropes articles](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/TheLastAngel):

> The story opens with the the death of a Compact Chariot at the hands of the first Human Dreadnaught. The Compact is a collection of alien species that seeks to conquer Humanity and absorb them into their ever expanding empire. They outnumber and out-gun Humanity, and their flagships, the Chariots have never been defeated. Nemesis breaks that streak, being the first to slay a Compact Chariot in combat. Despite this Nemesis is nearly crippled and her crew decimated. Oh, and one Compact ship gets away with Earth's coordinates.

....

> But not all is right. There's a warning in Common drawn on the ancient walls of the hangar bay, there's a pounding coming from deep within the ship, and sometimes... maybe... you think you hear laughter in the static on the radio. Grace is worried, her section leader is having nightmares, and Allyria... seems to know something.

Comment: What makes you say this is the book in question?

Comment: I think this is the one they're thinking of. The idea of a ship's AI going rogue is there, but it's only online, and from 2012.

Comment: The book I'm looking for was older than 2012 sadly :/. Although this does sound interesting.